# Which one to use, Much or Many?

Tags: countability

Are both these statements correct?

- How many onions do you want?
- How much onion do you want?

I feel as if the latter is wrong but I know not why.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31719/difference-between-much-many-a-lot-of-and-lots-of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both correct, given proper context.

If you want to ask someone how many **whole** onions, they want, you use the former:

> A: I need you to get onions from the store.
>   B: How many onions do you want?
>   A: Three or four, please.

Note that the answer can be fractional:

> A: I need onions for this recipe, can you get some from the store?
>   B: How many onions does the recipe call for?
>   A: One and a half large onions, so if you could buy two, that would be great.

This is the more common usage.

However, if you want a volume of onion, either chopped or prepared in some way, you would use "much".

> A: This recipe calls for a lot of chopped onion!
>   B: How much onion does it need?
>   A: Three cups!