# Is there any difference in meaning between "so much" and "so many" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between "so much" and "so many" in the following sentences?

> We don't exchange gifts so much for Christmas in Japan.
>
> We don't exchange so many gifts for Christmas in Japan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which one to use, Much or Many?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90351/which-one-to-use-much-or-many)

Comment: The possible duplicate does not cover the difference in interpretation (much->custom, many-> number of presents).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are quite different:

> We don't exchange gifts so much for Christmas in Japan.

"We don't *often* exchange gifts for Christmas in Japan"

> We don't exchange so many gifts for Christmas in Japan.

"We do exchange gifts, but not *as many* gifts (as they do in other countries)."

In the first sentence "so much" refers to an *amount* so the listener connects it to the *custom* of giving gifts, how often it's practiced.  In the second sentence "so many" refers to a countable *quantity* so the listener connects it to the *number* of gifts given.

By the way, I don't think either of these sentences is incorrect, and I understand the intended meaning of both, but to me the word order does not feel completely natural.  A more natural way to say each would be:

> In Japan, we don't usually give gifts for Christmas.
>
> In Japan, we don't give (as) many gifts for Christmas.

Comment: Hi. Can't "so many" mean "a lot of" in the second sentence in the OP?