# Error identification with "many"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, quantifiers

> **Many** of the population in the rural areas is composed of manual labourers.

In the above sentence, 'many' is the wrong word in this case. Could anyone please give the correction to the error?

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

> Most people in rural areas are manual labourers.

Another example:

> Most of the population in rural areas consists of manual labourers.

Comment: That's correct, but would you mind adding an explanation why it is?

Comment: Could you replace only ' many' by another word and keep the rest of the sentence?

Comment: Thank you. That's the question in my English grammar final test, and I chose 'most' too.:)

Comment: "Most" is a bit different in meaning from "many". "Many" is a portion which is not small; "most" is all but a few. For instance, if 50% of the population were manual laborers, that would be "many", but not "most".

Comment: If my answer helped you, please up-vote it and mark as answered.

Comment: See this [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31719/difference-between-much-many-a-lot-of-and-lots-of).

Comment: Campaigning for reputation? Strikes me as crass, but I may be "archaic."

Comment: Au contraire! We gotta keep this place as well as its inhabitants organized. You came, asked a question, if everything satisfies you, please mark the answer as answered. That's called discipline, my friend.