# Which one is correct? 'many thousands of animals ' or 'much thousands of animals'

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

'many thousands of animals ' or 'much thousands of animals'

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate, but the linked question never once mentions "many [number]". The OP will not find their answer on the other question. This question should be reopened so it can be answered correctly.

Comment: Since this was flagged for reopening and I do think there's room to write an answer that specifically addresses *many thousands of*, I've gone ahead and reopened it.  For reference, I'll leave a link to the duplicate target as a related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31719/230

Answer (score 1):

Many thousands.

Notwithstanding the inevitable exceptions that come with English, countable nouns (potatoes, rocks, thousands) generally use "many" whereas uncountable nouns (milk, sand, justice) use "much".

Answer (score 1):

*Many* for countable nouns is the correct one here but a better collocation would be :

Tens of thousands of animals ...