# Much vs a lot of [Why not to use much in positive sentences?]

Tags: word-usage, difference

I would like to know a few things about the use of "*much*" and "*a lot of*" in positive sentences.
First of all, I have been taught that in positive sentences I have to use "*a lot of*" and not "*much*". 
What's the reason for such a rule or recommendation?
Is it because "*much*" sounds very or extremely formal compared to "*a lot of*"?
I heard a person who teaches English say that "*much*" expresses a lesser amount than "*a lot of*" and that's why "*much*" doesn't have to be used in positive sentences. Is this true? Is it considered an error or wrong to use "*much*" in positive sentences?
My curiosity to know more about this topic is because often people who teach English just say "*in positive sentences use a lot of and not much*". But they don't give you a compelling reason.

Here are two couple of example sentences:

> 1. *I have much money.*
> 2. *I have a lot of money.*
> 3. *I have much water.*
> 4. *I have a lot of water.*

Comment: See this answer to the question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31719/difference-between-much-many-a-lot-of-and-lots-of

Comment: There are several words and phrases in English which are called _negative polarity items_: they occur only in negative or interrogative sentences, and not normally (or not with the same meaning) in positive declarative sentences. Other examples are _any_ (and _anywhere_, _anybody_ etc), _at all_, _the slightest_, _the least_, _few_ (but not _a few_). I don't know a reason for these: it is just a fact about English.