# there are much more questions that answering them will reveal more information about people

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I built a sentence but I don't really know if it's correct!

> there are much more questions that answering them will reveal more information about people

Is that correctly structured? does it make sense?

Which one is correct: answering them or giving them an answer.

I'm confused! could you please help me to correct my mistakes?

Comment: many more things, countable, much more coffee, uncountable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use "many" instead of "much", since questions is a countable noun. I'd also avoid using "more" twice. Finally while it does makes sense, it could be clearer with some reorganizing.

I would write this as:

> **There are many more questions that will reveal additional information about people when answered.**

Alternatively, if you want to stay closer to your structure, you could write:

> There are many more questions that when answered will reveal more information about people.

See also: [Difference between "much, many, a lot of and lots of"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31719/difference-between-much-many-a-lot-of-and-lots-of)